# AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute '__path__' django

Tags: python, django

I am getting the error "AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute '**path**'" 
I am using the django==1.3, python==2.7
application is developed in django==1.3

Error strace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "d:\ecenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 438
, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "d:\ecenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 379
, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "d:\ecenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191, in
 run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "d:\ecenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 219, in
 execute
    self.validate()
  File "d:\ecenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 249, in
 validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "d:\ecenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 3
6, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "d:\ecenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 146, in ge
t_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "d:\ecenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 61, in _po
pulate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "d:\ecenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 83, in loa
d_app
    if not module_has_submodule(app_module, 'models'):
  File "d:\ecenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in
module_has_submodule
    for entry in package.__path__:  # No __path__, then not a package.
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'
(ecenv)
```

I am using virtual envoirement "ecenv" where django==1.3 installed.
Please help me out for this previously this application was working fine.

Comment: what do you mean by "previously"?

Comment: Two weeks back i run the same project it was running fine,,,,,,,, after that i installed virtual enviorment.

Comment: are you sure that versions of django are the same (inside and outside virtualenv)?

Comment: no inside version is 1.3 and outeside version is 1.5. But i am using virtual enviorment. 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Version of Django inside virtualenv should be the (exactly) same as outside (where your project does work fine).

Here is your bug, that is fixed in 1.5 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13603